# Create Views Within ConstraintLayout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to create a simple layout with 3 rows of the `TextView` elements. The first and the last row contain just one text view each and the middle row contains two adjacent text views.
[Link to the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H94Bv.png)

Here is the xml for generating the views

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="TextView"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="TextView"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
```

I am trying to re-create the same view programatically with the following code:

```
        val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.main)
        val cs = ConstraintSet()
        cs.clone(layout)

        val textViews: MutableList<TextView> = ArrayList<TextView>()
        for (i  in 1..4) {
            val t = TextView(this)
            t.id = View.generateViewId()
            t.text = "Text" + i.toString()
            layout.addView(t)
            textViews.add(t)
        }

        //Just make suffixes similar to the layout xml
        val t1 = textViews[0]
        val t2 = textViews[1]
        val t3 = textViews[2]
        val t4 = textViews[3]

//    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
//    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
//    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
//    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        cs.connect(t1.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, t2.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        cs.connect(t1.id, ConstraintSet.END, layout.id, ConstraintSet.END)
        cs.connect(t1.id, ConstraintSet.START, layout.id, ConstraintSet.START)
        cs.connect(t1.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, layout.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)

//    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
//    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
//    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
//    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
        cs.connect(t2.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, t4.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        cs.connect(t2.id, ConstraintSet.END, t3.id, ConstraintSet.START)
        cs.connect(t2.id, ConstraintSet.START, layout.id, ConstraintSet.START)
        cs.connect(t2.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, t1.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)

//    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
//    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
//    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
//    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
        cs.connect(t3.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, t4.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        cs.connect(t3.id, ConstraintSet.END, layout.id, ConstraintSet.END)
        cs.connect(t3.id, ConstraintSet.START, t2.id, ConstraintSet.END)
        cs.connect(t3.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, t1.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)

//    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
//    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
//    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
//    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
        cs.connect(t4.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, layout.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        cs.connect(t4.id, ConstraintSet.END, layout.id, ConstraintSet.END)
        cs.connect(t4.id, ConstraintSet.START, layout.id, ConstraintSet.START)
        cs.connect(t4.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, t2.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
```

However this doesn't seem to work and all the text views are placed at the top-left corner of the display.

Could you please tell me how to make this piece of code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not enough just to clone the constraints and make the changes. The changes have to be applied to the *ConstraintLayout* using [ConstraintSet#applyTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#applyTo(androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout)).

Comment: Thank you so much!! Just one quick follow up question. The xml has `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` but there is no equivalent of that in the program. How does it work even without that?

Comment: @LomaHarshana `0dp` is just zero and it is set in the layout params of the view.